# CSS min-height doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have a parent `#out`, and a child `#in` div. The parent is absolute positioned, and it's min-height is 100%. It works, but if I set min-height: 100% to the child too, then it has no result.

HTML:

```
<div id="out"><div id="in">foo<br/>bar</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#out {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
}
#in {
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**It works only in Opera**
JSfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/TPyKS/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolute positioned elements are not computed in-line with other elements in the DOM. They are treated as their own floating elements. The height/width of other elements means nothing to them. Thus, you are not able to set a percentage based min-height/min-width on them. You would need to set the height/width explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Add `height: 100%;` to `#out`

```
#out {
    position: absolute;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Working DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/enve/TPyKS/1/

Answer (score 2):

Change of `min-height :100% to height :100% on #out` will work...

updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TPyKS/2/